# SQL Server Manager Studio creates lots of users folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

My SQL server setup is bread and butter, but after successfully installed SQL server into my laptop, I notice there are lots of empty folder in the `C:\Windows\Users` folders. I have a question whether I can move these folder into a specified folder for organisation? 
I'm using SQL Server Manager Studio 17

[image: Picture of my users folder]

Comment: Those are all folders created for the virtual service accounts you allowed the SQL Server installation to create.  You can't move them since those are actual accounts on your machine used to run the various services.  If you wanted to remove those account folders, you need to change the user context the corresponding services are running under, then delete the account and it's folders.

Comment: Note that those folders are created by Windows, not SSMS.

Comment: That are the user folders as there is an user created for every instance. So it's actually more of a Windows question: "Can the user folders of individual users be relocated?"

Comment: Besides Public folder, others folder are still created by Windows @DanGuzman?

Comment: @Vinnie What do you mean by the user context the corresponding services? You mean I can do this in Services app provided by Windows?

Comment: @AaronPham, yes. When the accounts are created during SQL installation, Windows creates the corresponding folders for the user profile.

Comment: @DanGuzman oh I see so what I should do is disconnect the service that connected to that account then mv it to designated place. Thank you